# RAlt getting stuck on AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I have this alphabetical list on a script I've made.

RAlt & a::Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeAlarmClock\FreeAlarmClock.exe
    RAlt & b::Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Brain Workshop\brainworkshop.exe
    RAlt & c::Run, H:\Sistema\Portables\Console2

It allows me to run several programs by pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + (letter of corresponding program) but sometimes (nad I still couldn't spot a pattern of when this happens). The Alt getting sort of "stuck" so if I start to type something it will start opening a bunch of programs just like I was holding Altt before typing each letter, but I'm not. Any ideas of what might be causing this behavior? I'm on Win8.

Comment: Same issue here. I didn't find the root cause but i found a workaround. I noticed this behaviour could be cancelled by hitting the LCtrl key after having hit the RAlt key. So i used this script`RAlt::
 send {RCtrl Down}{LAlt Down}
 keywait, RAlt
 send {RCtrl Up}{LAlt Up}{LCtrl Up}
Return`

Comment: this partially solve my problem: `KeyWait RAlt, L  ; (Wait for Alt to be released)` (put it at the begining of your code: the code will only be read when Alt will be released).

Answer (score 1):

May be it is keyboard problem? If no I think it is bug of AHK. AHK has tow very friendly forums http://ahkscript.org/boards/ and http://www.autohotkey.com/board/ . On both of them ahk  developers are reading bug forum, so you can post there about new bug or find any solution if exists.